# Calculate utilization/traffic intensity

Tags: cisco, routing, network

Hi how do i calculate utilization/traffic intensity of the link?

Let say I have a network with 400 web requests per second. Each request has average of 1Kb and the link to Internet is a 1.5Mbps link.

what is the formula i can use?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this homework? If not, please elaborate which problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Zac67 im trying to solve how to find the utilization of the question

Comment: You should ask your instructor. The answers you get here may not match what is required for your class. Unfortunately, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost never how link utilization would be measured.  It's typical (almost to the point of exclusion) to be measuring at some point of transmission/receipt to monitor counters on a given port.  In this case you'd look at the 1.5Mbps link and measure the number of packets and/or bits traversing it in each direction for a given timeframe.  This ends up accounting not only for the web requests but also any protocol overhead.

That said, for your exercise you could *approximate* a number by multiplying the number of *bits* for a given request.  Your notation isn't very precise, though.  Is the average web transaction 1 kilo**bit** or 1 kilo**byte**.  If the former, it's 1000 bits.  If the latter, 8192 bits.  In either case you'd multiply this number by 400 (your number per second) to get bits per second - again, either 400,000 or 3276800.  Divide this number by 1.5M to get link utilization - either 27% (lightly loaded) or 217% (heavily congested).

The other practical problem here, of course, is that you're only measuring in one direction.  Typically a client makes a request to a web server and then that server sends information back in the opposite direction to the client (...usually a much larger volume, as well).

Comment: The vagueness of the question is why we think this is a homework question.